# Seam Caving - Removal of seam in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, seam-carving

I'm implementing seam carving in python. So far, I've managed to find the lowest energy seam but I don't know how to implement removing it. Can somebody please explain this with pseudocode? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you know about this, but there is a modern implementation for it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Wand

That's a ImageMagick binding for python, and I think it would help you in anyways.